# Inaccurate position().left when using touchmove/mousemove

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been developing a sidebar which should allow users to drag the green tab to expand and collapse the sidebar. I believe it's mostly there but when dragging the sidebar the user encounters some resistence due to what I believe is inaccurate position().left values.

If you reduce the transition time on #side-panel to 5ms in the CSS the panel jumping is more noticeable.

```
var sidebar = (function(){

    var $document = $(document),
        $panel = $('#side-panel'),
        $tab = $panel.find('.btn'),
        panelWidth = $panel.width(),
        lastPanelPos = 0,
        panelOpen = false,
        hasTouch = false;

    var eventTypes = {
        eventStart: "mousedown",
        eventEnd: "mouseup",
        eventMove: "mousemove"
    };

    if($('html').hasClass('touch')){   

        hasTouch = true;

        eventTypes = {
            eventStart: "touchstart",
            eventEnd: "touchend",
            eventMove: "touchmove"
        };
    }

    // Tab drag starts
    function startDrag(){

        panelOpen = !panelOpen;

        $panel.bind(eventTypes.eventMove, changePanelPosition); 
    }

    // Tab drag finishes
    function dragEnd(){

            $panel.unbind(eventTypes.eventMove); 

            if(panelOpen){
                $panel.css("-webkit-transform", "translateX("+panelWidth+"px)");
            }else{
                $panel.css("-webkit-transform", "translateX(0px)");
            }
    }

    // Drag side panel
    function changePanelPosition(event){

        // Prevent android from cancelling touchmove event
        event.preventDefault();

        var parentOffset = $panel.position(),
            pageX = (hasTouch) ? event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX :  event.originalEvent.pageX,
            relX = pageX - parentOffset.left;

        if(relX < 0){
            relX = 0; 
        }else if(relX > panelWidth){
            relX = panelWidth;       
        }

        $panel.css("-webkit-transform", "translateX("+relX+"px)");

        lastPanelPos = relX;
    }

    // Events
    $tab.on(eventTypes.eventStart, startDrag);
    $document.on(eventTypes.eventEnd, dragEnd);
}());



<div id="side-panel">
    <div class="btn"></div>
</div>
```

Link to **[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Malcr001/w5f8M/)**

Comment: good work till now you want to drag the thing all the way and display only if the sidebar is dragged past a certain point or else return to initial position rather than opening up on click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't need to calculate `$panel.position().left` on every mouse move so I simply moved this to the top of the function. A work around perhaps but it seems to be fine now:
[LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/Malcr001/w5f8M/)

Comment: I'd also like to add that the CSS3 transition was also causing the element to jump as well but this is only visible on android's web view. When I removed the CSS transition all was fine.